# How can I see the core dumps produced by the policy-kit service?

Tags: policykit, systemd-coredump

I seem to have an issue with policy-kit. The output of `systemctl status --full --lines=100 polkit.service` is

```
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 systemd[1]: polkit.service: Changed failed -> start
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 systemd[1]: Starting Authorization Manager...
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 systemd[9219]: polkit.service: Executing: /usr/libexec/polkitd --no-debug
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 polkitd[9219]: started daemon version 0.105 using authority implementation `local' version `0.105'
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 systemd[1]: polkit.service: D-Bus name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 now owned by :1.140
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 systemd[1]: polkit.service: Changed start -> running
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 systemd[1]: polkit.service: Job 3133 polkit.service/start finished, result=done
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 systemd[1]: Started Authorization Manager.
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 polkitd(authority=local)[9219]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:2 (system bus name :1.83 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /o>
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 systemd[1]: polkit.service: Child 9219 belongs to polkit.service.
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 systemd[1]: polkit.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV**
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 systemd[1]: polkit.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 systemd[1]: polkit.service: Service will not restart (restart setting)
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 systemd[1]: polkit.service: Changed running -> failed
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 systemd[1]: polkit.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 systemd[1]: polkit.service: Consumed 119ms CPU time.
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 systemd[1]: polkit.service: Control group is empty.
Feb 12 18:35:46 flu-T430 systemd[1]: polkit.service: D-Bus name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 now not owned by anyone.
```

In particular, there is one line that says `Failed with result 'core-dump'`.
How do I get this core-dump?

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and `coredumpctl` is currently not installed.

Note: I found a file `/var/crash/_usr_libexec_polkitd.0.crash` but it's content is not human readable.

Solution: Running `sudo apt install systemd-coredump` lets me see the coredump by running `sudo coredumpctl dump --output=/path/to/file`

Comment: Does `coredumpctl list` mention it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. `coredumpctl` is not installed. This is something I might try.

Comment: I installed `coredumpctl` the meantime and was able to see the coredump! Thanks @steeldriver. In that sens, my question is answered. Yet, I don't understand why polkitd is producing a segfault. But that would be another question. :/